# Cannot define a session with bluprint

Tags: python, flask

I'm currently working on a connection system but when I define a session on the account.py page, the session isn't really defined.
File architecture :
|- app.py
|- APIs
|-- acount.py

app.py :

```
from flask import Flask, request, session
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from flask_session import Session
from datetime import timedelta
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
app.config['SESSION_PERMANENT'] = True
app.config['PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME'] = timedelta(days=1) 
app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)
Session(app)
CORS(app)

from APIs.account import account_api

app.register_blueprint(account_api)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

account.py

```
from flask import Blueprint, jsonify, request, session
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

account_api = Blueprint('account_api', __name__)
CORS(account_api)

class Account:
    # ....
    def login(self, email: str, password: str) -> dict:
         # ....
         session["user"] = "test"

    # ....


@account_api.route('/api/account/login', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin()
def login():
    try:
        email = request.json.get('email')
        password = request.json.get('password')
        if not email or not password:
            return jsonify({
                "code": 400,
                "message": "Missing email or password",
                "mess_code": "missing-credentials"
            })
        return jsonify(account_class.login(email, password))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return jsonify({
            "code": 500,
            "message": "Internal server error",
            "mess_code": "internal-server-error"
        })
```

I tried with `session.modified = True` but it doesn't change anything.